# Midas depth map: strange lines on sharp edge

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I'm using [Hugging Face's DPT large](https://huggingface.co/spaces/akhaliq/DPT-Large) to compute depth map.

Here is an example of my problem:

[image: artefacts]

(credit: [museum of Genêve](https://collections.geneve.ch/mah/oeuvre/souvenir-du-pilate/1938-0005))

The depth map contains some little white lines just above the mountains in the background.

How can I avoid them ?

btw: I have cloned the repo and it works well on my local computer, so I have access to the code. I can make pre/post-processing. But as non-specialist I cannot patch Midas itself.

EDIT: I'm using Midas exactly as in the example: https://huggingface.co/spaces/akhaliq/DPT-Large/blob/main/app.py By the way, the effect I describe is visible in [the offical demo](https://huggingface.co/spaces/akhaliq/DPT-Large).

EDIT: when I feed the extractor with the original 1148x790 image, the issue does not appears. It appears with a resized image 600x413. Thus a solution could be to only use non resized images.

Comment: can you show the code how you are using MIDAS? If there is no over or underflow in the pixel format (making very low values very high values (or vice-versa)) then probably those are artifacts of the NN itself. If that's the case you could try to filter them in a post-processing. For example with a median-filter.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself.
It turns out that the issue disappears with:

- Using the model "DPT_BEiT_L_512"
- `transform = midas_transforms.dpt_transform`
- 

```
 prediction = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(
            prediction.unsqueeze(1),
            size=img.shape[:2],
            mode="bilinear",   # <--- instead of bicubic
            antialias=True,
            align_corners=True,
```